# Algorithm to separate single contour of glyph into several strokes?

Tags: algorithms, clustering, polygons

A glyph contour contains points set {p}, a point contains tuple (x,y,on_curve).

Now, think about this need, converting contour of glyph X, for example, into to two contour parts or two strokes, point set of each stroke is similar with contour of glyph \ and /, topologically? Forgive my mouthful description.

Other examples (symbols at right of -> are shapes how these parts look like):

> A -> / \ -
>
> B -> | 3 or | ) )
>
> C -> C
>
> D -> | )
>
> E -> |---
>
> F -> |--
>
> G -> C-|

PS: I don't know whether there any algorithm exists for this need.
I use python and hope to make it with Python programming.

Comment: Welcome to CS@SE. What is the expected input, what is the required output? Have a look how glyphs are specified in [PostScript (Type 1)](https://wwwimages2.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/T1_SPEC.pdf) [supplement](https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/font/pdfs/5015.Type1_Supp.pdf).

Comment: @greybeard Thanks for your links, and the **input** is any glyph from any TrueType font, for example, arial, the **output** will be several generated glyphs, each of them consists of a subset of the source points set, maybe some other new points for curve painting, which can be saved into a font with new codepoint (maybe private use area).